# query retrieve data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have data in a table like this

```
insert into mytable (col1,col2,col3,col4) values(a,2,100,501);
insert into mytable (col1,col2,col3,col4) values(a,4,200,555);
insert into mytable (col1,col2,col3,col4) values(a,3,80,500);
insert into mytable (col1,col2,col3,col4) values(a,3,44,443);
```

---

Now i want a one select to retrieve data like this:

- amnt1 will assigned to col3 if col1=a and col2=2.
- amnt2 will assigned to col3 if col1=a and col2=3 and col4=500.

Results:

```
| amnt1 | amnt2 |
|---------------|
|   100 |    80 |
```

thnx

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. Also, there is no column `amnt1` and `amnt2` in your sample data (it has columns `col1` to `col4`).

Comment: @GMB  amnt1=100
amnt2=80 i want to display it in one line so amnt2 and amnt2 are aliases to col3

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60233962/edit) to show the result that you expect, as tabular text. Also, it is unclear whether you want an `update` or a `select` statement.

Comment: @GMB a select ,,i have edited the post ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select
    (select col3 from mytable where col1 = 'a' and col2 = 2) amnt1,
    (select col3 from mytable where col1 = 'a' and col2 = 3 and col4 = 500) amnt2
from dual
```

Note that this requires that only one record matches the two sets of conditions. In the event of multiple matching records, the above query would raise a runtime error; to avoid that, you can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select
    sum(case when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 2 then col3 end) amnt1,
    sum(case when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 3 and col4 = 500 then col3 end) amnt2
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from mytable m where m.col3='amnt1' and m.clo1='a' and m.col2=2

Comment: sorry... it would be >>
update mytable set col2='amnt1' where clo1='a' and col2=2